# Dot-boxplots from DataFrames

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, seaborn

Dataframes in Pandas have a [boxplot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) method, but is there any way to create **dot-boxplots** in Pandas, or otherwise with [seaborn](http://www.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/index.html)?

By a dot-boxplot, I mean a boxplot that **shows the actual data points** (or a relevant sample of them) inside the plot, e.g. like the example below (obtained in R).

[image]

Comment: Is this what your are looking for http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html

Comment: Thanks @pss I am aware of that. My question is specifically about dot boxplots. I wonder if there is an easy way to add the dots later (note the randomization of the dots along the `x` axis to make it easy to see them)

Comment: Use custom plot from `matplotlib`, feed it to pandas.boxplot as an `ax` argument, then make a dot plot into the same plot.

Comment: Thanks @CTZhu I was unable to follow that link (404 error on Github) (if you just paste the link it should work)

Comment: Why did I paste it as code? Sorry for that. Beeswarm plots in python: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mgymrek/pybeeswarm/blob/master/beeswarm_example.ipynb?create=1

Comment: It makes me sad that adding random noise to data is an acceptable plotting step.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For a more precise answer related to OP's question (with Pandas):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({ "A":np.random.normal(0.8,0.2,20),
                      "B":np.random.normal(0.8,0.1,20), 
                      "C":np.random.normal(0.9,0.1,20)} )

data.boxplot()

for i,d in enumerate(data):
    y = data[d]
    x = np.random.normal(i+1, 0.04, len(y))
    plt.plot(x, y, mfc = ["orange","blue","yellow"][i], mec='k', ms=7, marker="o", linestyle="None")

plt.hlines(1,0,4,linestyle="--")
```

[image: boxplot]

---

Old version (more generic) :

With matplotlib :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.normal(0,2,1000)
b = np.random.normal(-2,7,100)
data = [a,b]

plt.boxplot(data) # Or you can use the boxplot from Pandas

for i in [1,2]:
    y = data[i-1]
    x = np.random.normal(i, 0.02, len(y))
    plt.plot(x, y, 'r.', alpha=0.2)
```

Which gives that :
[image: dot-boxplot]

Inspired from [this tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/fonnesbeck/5850463/raw/a29d9ffb863bfab09ff6c1fc853e1d5bf69fe3e4/3.+Plotting+and+Visualization.ipynb)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 12):

This will be possible with seaborn version 0.6 (currently in the master branch on github) using the `stripplot` function. Here's an example:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips,
              size=4, jitter=True, edgecolor="gray")
```

[image]