# Automatic (whisker-sensitive) ylim in boxplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, seaborn

When plotting columns of a dataframe with pandas, e.g.

```
  df.boxplot()
```

the automatic adjustment of the `yaxis` can lead to a large amount of unused space in the plot. I wonder if this is because the dataframe has points that exceed the boxplot whiskers (but for some reason the outliers aren't displayed). If that is the case, what would be a good way to automatically adjust `ylim`  so that there isn't so much empty space in the plot?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib - How do I set ylim() for a series of plots?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415838/matplotlib-how-do-i-set-ylim-for-a-series-of-plots)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a combination of the seaborn style and the way matplotlib draws boxplots is hiding your outliers here.

If I generate some skewed data

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.lognormal(size=(100, 6)),
             columns=list("abcdef"))
```

And then use the `boxplot` method on the dataframe, I see something similar

```
x.boxplot()
```

[image]

But if you change the symbol used to plot outliers, you get

```
x.boxplot(sym="k.")
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the seaborn `boxplot` function, which does the same thing but with some nice aesthetics:

```
sns.boxplot(x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building on eumiro's answer in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686720/is-there-a-numpy-builtin-to-reject-outliers-from-a-list) post (I just extend it to pandas data frames you could do the following

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def reject_outliers(df, col_name, m=2):
    """ Returns data frame without outliers in the col_name column """
    return df[np.abs(df[col_name] - df[col_name].mean()) < m * df[col_name].std()]

# Create fake data
N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=np.random.rand(N), b=np.random.rand(N)))
df = df.append(dict(a=0.1, b=10), ignore_index=True)

# Strip outliers from the "b" column
df = reject_outliers(df, "b")
bp = df.boxplot()
```

The argument `m` is the number of standard deviations to ignore.

**EDIT:**

*Why do the whiskers not include the maximum outliers in the first place?*

There are several types of Boxplots as described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot). The `pandas` boxplot calls to `matplotlib`'s boxplot. If you take a look at the [documentation for this](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) the argument `whis`"Defines the length of the whiskers as a function of the inner quartile range. So it won't cover the entire range by design.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why the outliers were not shown in the original plot? I know that this is hard without seeing the data, but would it make sense that they didn't qualify as outliers considering the size of the plot?

Comment: If you want to see the original data [have a look at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519135/dot-boxplots-from-dataframes). Sorry I didn't really think about this when posting, I will answer with an edit in the original post.