# Matplotlib box plot fliers not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, seaborn

I was wondering if anyone had an issue with Matplotlib's box plot fliers not showing?

I literally copy-pasted this example here into a python script:
http://blog.bharatbhole.com/creating-boxplots-with-matplotlib/

...but the box plot fliers (outliers) are not showing. Does anyone know why I might not be seeing them? Sorry if this is a silly question, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why it doesn't work.

```
## Create data
np.random.seed(10)
collectn_1 = np.random.normal(100, 10, 200)
collectn_2 = np.random.normal(80, 30, 200)
collectn_3 = np.random.normal(90, 20, 200)
collectn_4 = np.random.normal(70, 25, 200)

## combine these different collections into a list    
data_to_plot = [collectn_1, collectn_2, collectn_3, collectn_4]

# Create a figure instance
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(9, 6))

# Create an axes instance
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Create the boxplot
bp = ax.boxplot(data_to_plot)
```

I also tried adding `showfliers=True` to the last line of that script, but it's still not working.

This is what I get as an output:

[image]

Comment: I reproduced the original by copy-pasting that code. Do you have anything else loaded? The grid / background coloring / unit typefaces all seem non-standard.

Comment: I'm using an iPython notebook... I should've mentioned it. That could be why. Do you know how to put the formatting back to the default Matplotlib settings?

Answer (score 35):

From the look of your plot, it seems you have imported the [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/) module. There is an [issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/102) with matplotlib boxplot fliers not showing up when seaborn is imported, even when fliers are explicitly enabled. Your code seem to be working fine when seaborn is not imported:

[image: Boxplot with fliers, no seaborn]

When seaborn is imported, you could do the following:

**Solution 1:**

Assuming you have imported seaborn like this:

`import seaborn as sns`

you can use the seaborn boxplot function:

`sns.boxplot(data_to_plot, ax=ax)`

resulting in:

[image: Seaborn boxplot with fliers]

**Solution 2:**

In case you want to keep using the matplotlib boxplot function (from [Automatic (whisker-sensitive) ylim in boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519432/automatic-whisker-sensitive-ylim-in-boxplots)):

`ax.boxplot(data_to_plot, sym='k.')`

resulting in:

[image: Matplotlib boxplot with fliers]

Answer (score 2):

You might not see fliers if the flier marker was set to `None`. The [page you linked to](http://blog.bharatbhole.com/creating-boxplots-with-matplotlib/) has a `for flier in bp['fliers']:` loop, which sets the flier marker style, color and alpha:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(10)
collectn_1 = np.random.normal(100, 10, 200)
collectn_2 = np.random.normal(80, 30, 200)
collectn_3 = np.random.normal(90, 20, 200)
collectn_4 = np.random.normal(70, 25, 200)

## combine these different collections into a list    
data_to_plot = [collectn_1, collectn_2, collectn_3, collectn_4]

# Create a figure instance
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(9, 6))

# Create an axes instance
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Create the boxplot
bp = ax.boxplot(data_to_plot, showfliers=True)

for flier in bp['fliers']:
    flier.set(marker='o', color='#e7298a', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Oddly enough, I saw the outliers when I ran the OP's code, but not when running your code.  Do you mean to also have `marker=None`?  Changing it to `marker='o'` generates your graph (for me).

Comment: @jedwards: Thanks for the heads-up. I copy-pasted the code with the wrong `marker` setting.

Comment: Hm. Yeah, I'm not getting a plot like that. I think it's because the iPython notebook I'm using has a weird formatting that I can't get rid of. Is there any easy way to obtain the flier (outlier) values? I've tried looking in `bp['fliers']`, but I can't find a way to extract the values from it. As long as I have the values, I think I can plot them over my box plot.

Comment: You could get the coordinates from `[line.get_data() for line in bp['fliers']]` but there should be a way to configure IPython or matplotlib/seaborn to display the fliers automatically.