# Matplotlib - How do I set ylim() for a series of plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I have a series of box plots I am trying to make, each of which has a different range.     I tried setting ylim by determining the max and min of each separate series.  However, the min in many cases is an outlier, and so the plot is compressed.   How can I select the same limit used by the 'whiskers' of the plot (plus a small margin)?

Eg, right now I'm doing this:

```
[In]
ax = df['feature'].boxplot()
ymax = max(df['feature']
ymin = min(df['feature']
ax.set_ylim([ymax,ymin])
```

I'd like to set ymax, ymin to be the whiskers of the box plot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an alternative to what @unutbu suggested, you could avoid plotting the outliers and then use `ax.margins(y=0)` (or some small `eps`) to scale the limits to the range of the whiskers.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.poisson(5, size=(100, 5)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#Note showfliers=False is more readable, but requires a recent version iirc
box = df.boxplot(ax=ax, sym='') 
ax.margins(y=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

And if you'd like a bit of room around the largest "whiskers", use `ax.margins(0.05)` to add 5% of the range instead of 0% of the range:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.poisson(5, size=(100, 5)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
box = df.boxplot(ax=ax, sym='')
ax.margins(y=0.05)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried to implement your solution, but am still having problems.     ax.margins(y=0.05) does not seem to set ylims and the plot shows up compressed.   One question:  I am using a form of boxplot df.boxplot(column =  'Feature1', by = 'Feature2') - e.g., I'm using a form of groupby to create the plot feature.   Would that affect this?

Comment: Joe, figured it out - the fliers were way outside of the whiskers.  setfliers = False solved the problem.  Works now.

Answer (score 4):

You could inspect the whiskers (`maplotlib.lines.Line2D` objects) returned by `df.boxplot()`. For example, if you call

```
bp = df.boxplot(ax=ax)
```

then `bp['whiskers']` will be a list of `Line2D` objects. You can find the `y-values` for each line using

```
yval = np.concatenate([line.get_ydata() for line in bp['whiskers']])
```

and then use `yval.min()` and `yval.max()` to determine the desired `y-limits`.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.poisson(5, size=(100, 5)))
bp = df.boxplot(ax=ax)
yval = np.concatenate([line.get_ydata() for line in bp['whiskers']])
eps = 1.0
ymin, ymax = yval.min()-eps, yval.max()+eps
ax.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could set `showfliers=False` in the boxplot, so the outliers don't get plotted.

Since you ask specifically about the whiskers, [this is how they are calculated](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot), with a default of 1.5:

> whis : float, sequence (default = 1.5) or string
>
> As a float, determines the reach of the whiskers past the first and
>   third quartiles (e.g., Q3 + whis*IQR, IQR = interquartile range,
>   Q3-Q1). Beyond the whiskers, data are considered outliers and are
>   plotted as individual points. Set this to an unreasonably high value
>   to force the whiskers to show the min and max values. Alternatively,
>   set this to an ascending sequence of percentile (e.g., [5, 95]) to set
>   the whiskers at specific percentiles of the data. Finally, whis can be
>   the string ‘range’ to force the whiskers to the min and max of the
>   data. In the edge case that the 25th and 75th percentiles are
>   equivalent, whis will be automatically set to ‘range’.

You could do the same calculation and set your `ylim` to that.